# Add a linebreak in an HTML table via XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table, line-breaks

I transform an XML file to HTML via XSL. 
In my html-table I have a column where I need to break the cell's content to a new line for each entry in one of my xml element-tags.

I'm not sure how to set up the xml-file for this.
Here's the output I was thinking of for my html-file:

```
<info>
line1<br/>
line2<br/>
line3<br/>
line4
</info>
```

and what doesn't work for me on the xsl-part:

```
    <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="info">
    <xsl:value-of select="." /> <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
```

I've tried wrapping the lines in the xml with `<ul>` and `<li>` but that didn't work. I think it's the xsl-part where I have the error. If I put a `<br/>` after the value-of statement it will output everything and then add the `<br/>` but of course I want the `<br/>` for each entry.

I hope you can tell me of a way how to set this up correctly.

Comment: Why not wrap each one in a <p></p> ?

Comment: What is the structure of the XML file? Specifically, does an `info` element contain subelements, or what? And the “output” you describe contains `<info>` tags, which are not HTML. So please specify the format of the XML data and the desired output format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="info/*[position() > 1]">
  <br /><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (as no source XML document is provided in the question):

```
<info>
  <t>line1</t>
  <t>line2</t>
  <t>line3</t>
  <t>line4</t>
  <t>line5</t>
</info>
```

**produces the wanted result** (`<info>` intentionally not generated as this isn't an HTML element):

```
line1<br/>
line2<br/>
line3<br/>
line4<br/>
line5
```

**Note 1**: This transformation was verified to produce exactly the above result with all of my XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 processors: MSXML3, MSXML4, MSXML6, .NET XslCompiledTransform, .NET XslTransform, Saxon 6.5.4, XML-SPY, Saxon 9.1.05, XQSharp, AltovaXML2011 (XML-SPY for XSLT 2.0).

**Note 2**: If you *really* want to have the result wrapped int an `<info>` element, just add this template:

```
 <xsl:template match="info">
  <info>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </info>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do as follows. The xml input file contains a structure like

```
<info>
    <line>line1</line>
    <line>line2</line>
    <line>line3</line>
    <line>line4</line>
</info>
```

And the xslt contains the following:

```
<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="info/line">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

This will result in (output method used is `html` which usually makes the `br` elements not being closed in the result file):

```
<td>
    line1<br>
    line2<br>
    line3<br>
    line4<br>
</td>
```

If you need to drop the final `br` then you will have to add some more xsl code.